# Is it ok to use HTML strings in JS code while using jquery templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-templates

In our app we use javascript to pump the incoming JSON data into presentable HTML. I've ben using JQuery template for this.
I have begun to notice that I've been using more and more html Strings In JS code. for ex:

```
render = function(data, parent){

   var header, analyticsHtml, analyticsTmpl;
   header= parent.find(".header");
   header.append('<H3>'+ i18n['header']+'</H3>');
   analyticsHtml = '<div><div class="floatLeft" id="analytics"><div class="gt"><span>01</span><br />i18n['Text1']</div></div></div>';
   parent.append(analyticsHtml);
   analyticsTmpl = "....blah...";

   $('#analytics').append($.tmpl(analyticsTmpl, data));
   .
   .
   .

}
```

Is it ok to use html strings within JS code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's OK, but you have to escape the quote characters you use with "\".

```
analyticsHtml = '<div><div class="floatLeft" id="analytics"><div class="gt"><span>01</span><br />' + i18n['Text1'] + '</div></div></div>';
```

In your code, you forgot the "+" operators for the "i18n" array reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's fine to do that. Something I do is to try to define the templates in a non-local variable at the top of the class/codefile/closure, and if they're long, split them over multiple lines to make it more readable,

Comment: Accessing non-local variables takes more time than instance/global variables. Keeping that in mind why would you want to do it even if the template is long and is being used only in that function.

Comment: I hadn't heard that one before - do you have a link or benchmark? Would be interesting to know.